# Changing the color of a polygon continuously using the slider (psychopy, python)

Tags: python, colors, slider, polygon, psychopy

we are trying to find the answer to our question in the title. To be more specific:

- There are supposed to be 3 slider components that are regulating blue, red and yellow color parts.
- The sliders have a scale from 1 to 100 for each color
- There is supposed to be a little component next to each slider that shows the current value of the slider
- There are also two rectangles:
  one showing a "goal-setting" (a pre-set color that the participants are supposed to recreate using the sliders)
  and another rectangle that shows the current state and changes the color according to the values of the slider

so e.g. the pre-set goal color is green which means that the participant should idealy use the slider for yellow and blue to get the color of the "state-rectangle" as near to the goal setting as possible.

We are total beginners in programming in general so thanks in advance for every advice!

We already set up the sliders, the two rectangles and also the little windows that are supposed to show the current value of the slider (fot that we used normal text components but we are not sure if that will work)
We were trying a bunch of different codes but could not find a specific problem, they all did not work out in general. But as I said we are total beginners and have no idea how to use codes.

Comment: It would be nice, if you also could include some important code of your program, so that others can help you better.